# Force C# to use the intended Timer

Tags: c#, timer

I want to use System.Timers.Timer , but because this is a WinForm there's already System.Windows.Forms.Timer. Instead of doing `System.Timers.Timer timerOne = new System.Timers.Timer();`, is there a way to do `Timer timerOne = new Timer();` by forcing the use of System.Timers.Timer (or ignoring System.Windows.Forms.Timer)?

Comment: Consider this a less-than-subtle hint that you should *not* use System.Timers.Timer.  And a reason to spell it out completely because a reader of your code will not expect it.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, I'm a little confused by your comment. I understand that one might not see the alias and assume it's the Windows.Form version. Otherwise, why shouldn't I use System.Timers.Timer? It's different from System.Windows.Forms.Timer as far as I understand.

Comment: Yes, it's different.  It is very incompatible with almost all Winforms specific code you'd write.  Very few Winforms classes are thread-safe.  Solving that with Control.Begin/Invoke defeats the point of using that timer.

Comment: I may be wrong here, but aren't events raised by Windows.Form versions ignored/not raised if the UI thread is busy, while the Timers version's events are not? This may be out-dated info (circa 2004): [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx#S2)

Comment: Don't be such a bully, @Hans. :) As with anything else it's fine to use Timers.Timer if you educate yourself on how it works. And using Control.Invoke doesn't have to defeat the purpose: you may want to do a bunch of processing on the worker thread and _then_ invoke to update the UI at the last moment.

Comment: @Charles - I could go on how that timer is next to impossible to stop and how it evilly swallows *all* exceptions.  Problem is: that's not what he asked.  Btw: don't mutate a struct :)

Comment: I would actually recommend using System.Threading.Timer unless you need any of the additional features of Timers.Timer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a using Timer = System.Timers.Timer; to the top of your source file. Note that this alias is only going to work within the file in which it's declared; you'll have to add it to each file in which you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can always alias the class name:

```
// Other Includes
using System.Linq;
using MyTimer = System.Timers.Timer;

MyTimer x = new MyTimer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, but not as pretty as the others, is to create your own class and inherit it from timer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the alias form of the [using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;
```